# how to read a excel sheet and store it in a java script array and show it as a table in a html

Tags: angularjs, excel

How do I read an excel sheet and store it in a Javascript array and show it as a table in a html? I also want to submit a new record through an html form and it have to append in a excel and after refreshing the page the table should have to display all the records from the table. I am doing an application of issue management in html and angularjs. I don't want to add any db. I need to have an excel as a backend. I need to pull datas from a excel sheet and store it in a json array and json array value have to be displayed as a table in html. And new issues have to be created and it should be append in a excel sheet

Comment: I would generally advise Angular not to be the best framework to achieve this, there is very little online about parsing xls files using angular (Git Directives etc). It might be possible through Javascript (http://codetheory.in/parse-read-excel-files-xls-xlsx-javascript/) but I don't think it's necessarily the "correct" or most efficient way of doing it. Personally, I'd built an API layer and manipulate the document through server code and pass your JSON to and from the API layer.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/excel-as-json).  I believe this will help you.